# How to invoke "authenticated" functions on GCP cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

On GCP cloud functions if I unchecked the **"Allow unauthenticated invocations"**, I can access the HTTP API only via an access token provided `gcloud auth print-access-token` command, which is a JWT token, how can I get similar access token via **postman**, so that my mobile app can get similar token and be able to invoke cloud function? Should I set up my own OAuth server which is on GCP, if **yes** how?

*PS*: *Please refer this question* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245338/why-doesnt-granting-allauthenticatedusers-member-the-cloud-functions-invoker/58248009)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
curl -i https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME] -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

I also suggest checking the [Authenticating Developers, Functions, and End-users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) documentation for more ways to authenticate with Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: Check the documentation also ;)

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not clear with the question. I have a user logged in via firebase, every time they log in, I get their id_token, how can I connect my firebase user to GCP cloud functions has an authenticated user so that I can invoke CF?@gu

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I saw this ans of yours [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245338/why-doesnt-granting-allauthenticatedusers-member-the-cloud-functions-invoker/58248009#58248009]

Comment: @mj21 Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can generate the token programmatically -

```
// const url = 'https://TARGET_URL';
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();

async function request() {
  if (!targetAudience) {
    // Use the request URL hostname as the target audience for requests.
    const {URL} = require('url');
    targetAudience = new URL(url).origin;
  }
  console.info(`request ${url} with target audience ${targetAudience}`);
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.info(res.data);
}

request().catch(err => {
  console.error(err.message);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Once token is generated you can pass it in header as -

```
Authorization: Bearer ${myToken}
```

Read further documentations here - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#functions-bearer-token-example-nodejs