# Authenticated HTTP Request to External API

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project.

I am calling an external api via cloud function in the hope the api key (stored in env variable) will be less discoverable.

While I have managed to get the following code working in the emulator, it doesn't work after deployment.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const makeRequest = async (req, res) => {

  const apiKey = process.env.KEY1;
  const apiUrl = `[externalAPIurl]&key=${apiKey}`;


  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const data = await response.json();

    res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
};

exports.helloWorld = onRequest(makeRequest);
```

CORS is flagged as the problem. Postman tells me that it's a lack of authentication being passed in the header (error 403).

I have struggled to adapt existing code (Google samples/turtorials, and community-provided excerpts). For example:

1. The following excludes req, res parameters and isn't obviously amenable to calling an external api (url)
   https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-bearer-token?hl=en
2. The following documents how one might create authenticated functions: [How to invoke "authenticated" functions on GCP cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589339/how-to-invoke-authenticated-functions-on-gcp-cloud-functions)
   But the linked documentation suggests the approach is for development purposes (only?): https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating
3. This is very close, but is 1st gen and lacks the external api call: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/Node-1st-gen/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js

For context, the plan is to anonymously authenticate all users of the website. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be sweet.

Comment: Can you post the full error? Also, do you have billing enabled?

Comment: Hey Jeremy. I ended up adapting a firebase callable function instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable
Thanks though (billing was enabled) - have requested closure of this question